# Xml parsing issue with google finance

Tags: php, xml

Can someone help me parse a simple quote from google finance xml using php? Here is the xml doc:

http://www.google.com/ig/api?stock=CIEL3&q=BVMF

Right now, I have

```
$xmlUrl = "http://www.google.com/ig/api?stock=CIEL3&q=BVMF";
$xmlStr = file_get_contents($xmlUrl);
$xmlObj = simplexml_load_string($xmlStr);
echo $xmlObj->finance->symbol[0];
```

How can I print only the 57.10 from line

```
<last data="57.10"/>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the [`attributes()`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php) method to access the attributes of the object:

```
echo $xmlObj->finance->last->attributes()->data;
```

[**Demo!**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/4XvsK2)